# Makefile install target sometimes working, sometimes not

Tags: build, open-source, mono, makefile, monodevelop

I'm currently working on a project that should also provide a source package to be packaged into linux systems. Since I'm using monodevelop, I used

```
mdtool generate-makefiles AudioCuesheetEditor.sln --simple-makefiles
```

to generate makefiles,etc. But there is a little problem. On some system everything works fine when running the last step

```
make install
```

but sometimes not. The output then says

```
[root@VMFedora17 Downloads]# make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make pre-install-local-hook prefix=/usr/local
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make install-satellite-assemblies prefix=/usr/local
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
cp   bin/Release /usr/local/lib/AudioCuesheetEditor
cp: omitting directory `bin/Release'
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/lib/AudioCuesheetEditor] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make[1]: *** [install-local] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sven/Downloads'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

This was run on a Fedora 17 Linux with KDE installed. On another Fedora 17 KDE everything went perfect.

Could somebody help me, where the error is?

Makefile can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/140/tree/trunk/Quellcode/AudioCuesheetEditor.make

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No one any idea? I'm really stuck with this problem since I have no idea where to start to search for the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

From your output and the link you provided, I found the error in the following snippet:

```
install-local: $(ASSEMBLY) $(ASSEMBLY_MDB)
    make pre-install-local-hook prefix=$(prefix)
    make install-satellite-assemblies prefix=$(prefix)
    mkdir -p '$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE)'
    $(call cp,$(ASSEMBLY),$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE))
```

I guess $(ASSEMBLY) was a directory, but I am not sure. And the command **cp** without the parameter -r will not copy the directory recursively. You can try to modify

```
$(call cp,$(ASSEMBLY),$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE))
```

to

```
$(call cp,-r,$(ASSEMBLY),$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE))
```

or

```
cp -r $(ASSEMBLY) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE)
```

Additionally, if you want to find out why the original works on one machine but not on the another, you can add a command:

```
echo $(ASSEMBLY)
```

before the above command to see if the output of them are different on different machines.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that didn't work. It keeps working sometimes and sometimes not. Yes, $(ASSEMBLY) seems to be "bin/Release" but why does it sometimes work? I just do not understand, why it sometimes works and sometimes not (on the same machine).

Comment: Is bin/Release is a directory or a file? I guess it was a file. But when encountering error, it indicated it was a directory.

Comment: bin/Release is the output directory.

Comment: Could you try to modify $(call cp,$(ASSEMBLY),$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE)) to cp -r $(ASSEMBLY)/* $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/$(PACKAGE)?